# How to rename a Data Lake Gen2 folder using the Azure CLI?

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-cli, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm using Azure Data Lake Gen2 and I have a folder named **myfolder** with *1000s* of files. Is there a command on the Azure Storage CLI for **renaming the folder** and/or **move the entire folder to another location** of the ADLS Gen2?

Inside Azure Databricks I can easily leverage the linux mv bash command:

- `mv myfolder newname` for renaming **myfolder**
- `mv myfolder /dbfs/mount/myadls/target/` for moving **myfolder** to a **target** folder.

Is there a simple way of doing the same with the Azure CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE: An ADLS Gen2 CLI is now available**

We can rename or move a directory by using the `az storage fs directory move` command.

**Example 1**: Renaming a directory from the name `my-directory` to the name `my-new-directory` in the same file system:

```sh
az storage fs directory move -n my-directory -f my-file-system --new-directory "my-file-system/my-new-directory" --account-name mystorageaccount --auth-mode login
```

**Example 2**: This example moves a directory to a file system named `my-second-file-system`.

```sh
az storage fs directory move -n my-directory -f my-file-system --new-directory "my-second-file-system/my
```

For more info, here's the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-cli#rename-or-move-a-directory).

Answer (score 2):

According to my research,  if you want to manage Data Lake Gen2 directories, now we just can use [Azure data lake gen2 rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/data-lake-storage-gen2). For more details, please refer to the  [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues#support-for-other-blob-storage-features).

For example, if you want to rename your folder, you can use [the rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/create)

```
PuT https://<your account name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<file system name>/<new folder name>
Header:
x-ms-rename-source : /<file system name>/<orginal folder name>
Authorization : Bearer access token.
```

Regarding how to call the rest api， please refer to the following steps 
1. Create a service principal

```
az login
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ServicePrincipalName
```

2. assign role to the service principal

```
az role assignment create \
    --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" \
    --assignee < your service principal name> \
    --scope "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>"
```

3. Call the rest api

```
az login --service-principal  --username <your service principal app id> --password <your service principal password>--tenant <your tenant id>

az rest --method put --uri https://testadls05.dfs.core.windows.net/test/testFolder --resource https://storage.azure.com --headers x-ms-rename-source=/test/testFolder1
```

[image]
[image]